# Swift Showing only one AlertView if there is multiple AlertView pushed

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

If I have more than one AlertView on a controller, how to make it only show the last AlertView if all of them triggered respectively? Please look code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.getAPI1()
    self.getAPI2()
    self.getAPI3()
}

func getAPI1() {
    do {
         // try ... Get API Process
    } catch {
         let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "ERROR", message: "There is an error on getAPI1()", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
         alertView.show()
    }
}

func getAPI2() {
    do {
         // try ... Get API Process
    } catch {
         let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "ERROR", message: "There is an error on getAPI2()", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
         alertView.show()
    }
}

func getAPI3() {
    do {
         // try ... Get API Process
    } catch {
         let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "ERROR", message: "There is an error on getAPI3()", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
         alertView.show()
    }
}
```

Since getAPI1, getAPI2 and getAPI3 needs to be executed no matter if one of them is getting error, how to show the last AlertView only? Thank you.

Comment: use UIAlertController instead, which will just follow normal UIViewController logic. (i.e: presentViewController:animated:), you can present them in any order you would like

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable to store which alert is being active and displayed currently.

```
var activeAlert : UIAlertView! = nil
```

Every time you show the alert check if any alert is being shown before. You can check it like this

```
if nil != activeAlert {
    activeAlert.dismissWithClickedButtonIndex(-1, animated: false)
    //show your new alert here
}
```

This way it will be ensured that always the last alert is shown. Make sure you are implementing `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method of `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol. Also `UIAlertView` is deprecated from iOS 9.0 so i recommend you using `UIAlertViewController` instead